# Regarding message listener in asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I have created 3 activities. First is **loginactivity** to check login details.After Login is successfull it jumps to **displayactivity** which i used to show contacts of a person in a listview.After selecting any contact from listview it jumps to 3 activity which is **messageactivity** to show the chatting between 2 users. Now my question is Every time i open **messageactivity from displayactivity**. When I try to send Message from **messageActivity**
using *ChatManager* it creates a new listener for that particular user.But i have also created a one different message Listener. Now what happens:
1. When i starts application it creates listener to listen to messages.
2. When i try to send message it creates another listener for that particular user.

So, it starts duplicating messages? Any Idea. Where i am wrong I am new in XMPP and Android Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use only one packet listener in service, then send broadcast from that service when xmpp message is received, who so ever Activity want that message can use it after that